# Datetime Pandas Function Only Converting Single Series

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I am working with several pandas dataframes, each of which have timestamps in a format like: "2018-01-01 00:00:00 UTC". I wrote a function to be able to scan every single one of the columns of the dataframe and change the columns that have data in this format. Here's the function:

```
def utc_converter(dataframe, timezone):
    columns = dataframe.columns.tolist()
    for column in columns:
        try:
            s = pd.to_datetime(dataframe[column], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC', utc=True)
        except ValueError:
            continue
        s.dt.tz_convert(timezone)
        s = s.dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
        dataframe[column] = s
    dataframe = dataframe.replace(to_replace=pd.NaT, value=np.nan)
    return dataframe
```

For some reason, whenever I run the function on a dataframe, it's only catching the first column, and it's not looping through any of the rest. Anyone have any idea what I've done wrong? I've been scratching my head for a bit now.

Thanks!

Comment: for converting try data.columnname = pd.to_datetime(data['columnname'])

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.to_datetime()`, with `strftime()` to re-format your dates:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC', utc=True).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Note that this will return a column of type `str`, so to convert back to `datetime` simply do:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just consider the first row to determine *which* columns are in scope. Then use `pd.to_datetime` on selected columns via `pd.DataFrame.apply`. Here's a demo:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['2018-01-01 00:00:00 UTC', 0, 341.3214, 'test1',
                    '2019-01-01 00:00:00 UTC'],
                   ['2015-01-01 00:00:00 UTC', 46, 235.54, 'test2',
                    '2020-01-01 00:00:00 UTC']],
                  columns=['date1', 'int', 'float', 'string', 'date2'])

dt_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC'
L = [pd.to_datetime(i, errors='coerce', format=dt_format) for i in df.iloc[0].values]
dt_cols = df.columns[pd.Series(L).notnull()]

df[dt_cols] = df[dt_cols].apply(pd.to_datetime, format=dt_format)
```

Result:

```
print(df)

       date1  int     float string      date2
0 2018-01-01    0  341.3214  test1 2019-01-01
1 2015-01-01   46  235.5400  test2 2020-01-01

print(df.dtypes)

date1     datetime64[ns]
int                int64
float            float64
string            object
date2     datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```